# Splitting GAMS equation using if else statements

Tags: variables, optimization, conditional-statements, set, gams-math

I have a working GAMS optimization model using LP. I want to modify one of my equations so that it excludes one of the terms when t = 1. Here's the simplification of this problem:

Set  t         "time in hours"              / 1 * 8760/ ;

**If t = 1:**
vDemand(t) =e= p1*(vInternal(t) - pAmbient(t))

**else:**
vDemand(t) =e= p1*(vInternal(t) - pAmbient(t)) + p2*(vInternal(t) - vInternal(t-1))

How do I modify this vDemand equation while keeping my optimization linear?

I looked up and tried the different ways to incorporate conditional statements on GAMS, but not successful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vDemand(t) =e= p1*(vInternal(t) - pAmbient(t)) + (p2*(vInternal(t) - vInternal(t-1)))$(ord(t)>1);
```

The `$` condition at the end of the second term makes sure, that that part is only used, if it is not the first element of the set `t`.